# Thymeleaf count matches in each loop (Array of Objects)

Tags: java, thymeleaf

```
Counter = 0

<div th:each="student: ${students}">
    <div th:if="${student.name == 'Felix'}">
     Counter = Counter + 1
    <div/>
</div>

<div th:text="${Counter}"></div>
```

Hello everybody, I still struggle with conditional rendering based on the match in an array. Is there an Option to render something when `Counter > 0`? I know the **code is not valid**, but this is only the **desired Output**.
I know about `th:if` or course. A simple `contains()` does not work since the array contains multiple objects, not strings or something easy to work with.

Does anyone know an answer?

Comment: do you need to render only if the `name` of `Felix` exists at least once in the list of students?  Or do you need to print the number of times it occurs?

Comment: Could be sufficient depending on your needs: `th:if="${#lists.contains(student.name, 'Felix')}"`.  Otherwise, you can go with Metroids answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do it this way.  You shouldn't  be updating variables in Thymeleaf markup ever.  Either:

1. Add the count before rendering (on the model).
2. Use [collection selection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-selection).

   ```
   <div th:text="${#lists.size(students.?[name == 'Felix'])}" />
   ```

Comment: might want to do `#strings.equals(name, 'Felix')`, no?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... that's special syntax for the [collection selection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-selection).

Comment: thank you for all your comments. I came across `<script th:inline="javascript">` which seems to solve my problem, even though it´s not perfectly clean (i guess at least). I have no Java Experience and using a open source 3rd party software, so this seems easier

Comment: Not sure whether it would be evaluated differently, but this? 
  `<div th:text="${#lists.size(students.?['Felix'.equals(name)])}" />` . Meant to write to use `.equals` instead of `==`: